# Java threads holding a monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I was reading about java threads and happened to read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077137/java-concurrency/synchronizing-threads-in-java--part-1.html) blog.
In the blog I came across a statement:

*During the execution of a synchronized method, the thread holds the monitor for that method's object, or if the method is static, it holds the monitor for that method's class.*

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between:

- a thread is holding the monitor for methods object
- a thread is holding the monitor for methods class

Answer (score 4):

It means that a synchronized instance method is broadly equivalent to:

```
public class FooClass {
    public void foo() {
        synchronized(this) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas a synchronized static method is broadly equivalent to:

```
public class FooClass {
    public static void foo() {
        synchronized(FooClass.class) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So in the instance method case it will synchronize on an instance of `FooClass` (and calls to `foo` in other threads *on other instances* will not block), whereas in the static method case it synchronizes on the `Class` object itself.

Note that for the static method version, it's the *class containing the method* which is important - even if the method is notionally called "on" a subclass (e.g. `SubFooClass.foo()`) the method still obtains a monitor on the class in which it's declared.

See [JLS section 8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can rougly translate, in a class `Foo`, say:

```
public synchronized foo()
{
    doSomething();
}
```

to:

```
public foo()
{
    synchronized(this) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Whereas:

```
public static synchronized foo()
{
    doSomething();
}
```

translates (roughly) to:

```
public static foo()
{
    synchronized(Foo.class) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

In the first case, you synchronize against the current instance of `Foo` (`this`). In the second case, you synchronize against the `Class` object (all `Class` objects are singletons, this is why it works).

Answer (score 0):

on a non static method, the lock is on the instance (this); ie your method is equivalent to:

```
public void method(){
    synchronised(this){
        //my code
    }
}
```

on a static method, there is no instance (you can't reference this in a static method). So the lock is on the actual class object (MyObject.class).

```
public static void method(){
    synchronised(MyClass.class){
        //my code
    }
}
```

Hence with 1 synchronised methods and 1 synchronised static method, the two can execute at the same time as they nothing prevents them from running in parallel, the locks being on different objects.